# Mac OS X El Capitan and more than one Sprite Kit SKView

Tags: xcode, macos, performance, sprite-kit

Developing on a Mac with El Capitan and Xcode 7.2:

If I have a project with one Window, that has a `SKScene` for `SpriteKit`, then I will get the needed 60 fps and everything works as expected. But as soon as I define a second window with an `SKScene` in it, then I will have only 30 fps in my first window, even if the second window is not used at all and not even a `Referencing Outlet` for the second window is defined. The second window only exists in `MainMenu.xib` and is not used at all.

I need four `Sprite Kit Windows` with one scene in it for my projects, so I get a very poor updating performance. Programs work fine with Yosemite but as soon as I run them in El Capitan this problem occurs.

I would be very lucky for any suggestions. Problem is the same in older Xcode versions and the newest one (7.2). I have compiled final programs that are a few month old and ones which are new, all have the same issue, so I think it has nothing to do with Xcode but with the El Capitan Mac OS.

When setting the `SKView` into the *"Core Animation Layer"*, in Xcode "`MainMenu.xib`", dialog page *"View Effects Inspector"* and check all the `SKViews` to set into *"Core Animation Layer"*, then everything is fine for small Animations. As soon as the 60 fps cannot reched, because I have too much objects in the scene, the View is only updated once a second and this looks horrible. With Yosemite, the Scene was updates 30 times a second, which is really enough for my purpose.

Because this does not depend on the Xcode version, it seems that Apple has changed something to "optimize" the screen redrawing and if it is not possible to make 60 fps, then the drawing is not made with 30 fps or whatever is possible, but only with 1 fps. I also tried "Can Draw Concurrently" on the "Attributes Inspector" page but this makes no difference at all. I use a new 8-core Mac Pro with D700 graphic. So this should not be the reason.

I also tried to limit the screen updates with `myView.frameInterval = 30` from which I expected that only two updates per second are made. But this command seems to do absolutely nothing. The `myView.allowsTransparency = ...` produces an exception, regardless if true or false. `myView.asynchronous = true` makes the updates as smooth as in Yosemite. But it needs 30 seconds or so to pull down a menu (with a big node count, of course) and you cannot work with the program. This is - in the result - not identically to the "Can Draw Concurrently" option in Xcode.

Is it possible to change to the Yosemite rendering, because all described options seem to be not optimal.

Any ideas how to handle a large node-count or restrict the update-rate so that the program can be quit comfortably by menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now developed a workaround. With some additional lines of code I get the same results in Yosemite and in El Capitan. The Performance in El Capitan is about twice as quick than in Yosemite.

1. "`SKView`" must be set into the "`Core Animation Layer`" in "`MainMenu.xib`" or you will see no Sprite at all
2. You can define as much "`SKViews`" as you want. I will only show one as an example
3. The Definition of the Views in the `AppDelegate` Class needs some more code:

   ```
   class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
   {
       @IBOutlet var myWindow1: NSWindow!
       @IBOutlet var mySKView1: SKView!

       // other functions here as needed

       func applicationDidFinishLaunching (aNotification: NSNotification)
       {
           let scene_size = CGSizeMake(1280.0, 800.0) // For example 1280x800 Pixel
           let myScene1 = myScene1Class(size: scene_size)
           mySKView1.scaleMode = .ResizeFill // works for me better than ".AspectFill"
           mySKView1.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
           mySKView1.asynchronous = true // This makes the difference in smooth Display-Speed
           mySKView1.showsFPS = false
           mySKView1.showsNodeCount = false
           mySKView1.presentScene(myScene1)
           mySKView1.paused = true // This makes the difference in Event-Handling
           // Start your Main-Program-Process here
       }
   }
   ```

   4. The "Can Draw Concurrently" Option in "MainMenu.xib" can be set or not, it makes no difference

Screen Updates start automatically when adding Sprites and showing the windows. When I present the scene in "`AppDelegate`", no sprite is in it. This is done by my automatic initialization for every program.

If you want, you can play with the two options "`mySKView1.asynchronous = true`" and "`mySKView1.paused = true`". If you set one to "`false`", you can see the problems. Note, that you must define much nodes to make this problem visible at all, because if your Mac reaches 60 fps because you have less nodes, than everything seems fine regardless which option you choose. And you will nedd two "`SKViews`" or more, in one or more Windows.

Tested with 130000 (130k!) nodes, making about 20 fps. Tested with 260000 (260k!) nodes, making about 10 fps. Three other "`SKViews`" defined with no sprites to test the whole thing.